# Creating registry key (string): why one way works and the other way not

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code:

```
RegistryKey macroExcel = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Office\" + DezePc.OfficeVersie + @".0\Excel\Security");
if (macroExcel == null)
{
macroExcel = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Office\" + DeOfficeVersie + @".0\Excel\Security");
}
```

Now, i if i create a Subkey this way if works fine:

```
Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Office\" + DeOfficeVersie + @".0\Excel\Security").SetValue("VBAWarnings", "1", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

But if i do it this way it fails:

```
macroExcel.SetValue("VBAWarnings", "1", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

[image]

Comment: Is the first code block a typo? you have string + if statement?

Comment: @AlexAnderson, yes it was a typo. I changed it

Comment: @Nomistake, try `Registry.SetValue(FatherRegistryKey.Name, "newValueName", "30");`

Comment: you may need to specify you want write permissions, when you open the key try `Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Office\" + DeOfficeVersie + @".0\Excel\Security", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree).SetValue("VBAWarnings", "1", RegistryValueKind.String);`

Comment: ok, but but what i find strange is that when i use the full path Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Office\" + DeOfficeVersie + @".0\Excel\Security") it works but with a variable macroExcel (which is actually the same as the full path) it gives me thsi error

Comment: So, what is the difference?

Comment: i believe createsubkey has an overload that takes (string,bool).  the bool will open the key for write if true.